# Error en firma detachada Java

Tags: java, criptografía, bouncycastle, smime

Requiero firmar cualquier documento o texto con CMS smime en java, tengo el siguiente código pero el provider y el signerAlgorithm generan error:

```
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            X509Certificate certificado = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate("EMPLEADO");
            PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("EMPLEADO", null);

            List<X509Certificate> certList = new ArrayList<X509Certificate>();
            byte[] text = "Text to sign".getBytes();
            CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(text);

            certList.add(certificado);

            Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);

            DigestCalculatorProvider digProvider = new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BCFIPS").build();
            JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder signerInfoGeneratorBuilder = new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(digProvider);

            ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(CMSSignedDataGenerator.DIGEST_SHA1).setProvider("BCFIPS").build(key);

            CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();

            gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(signerInfoGeneratorBuilder.build(signer, certificado));

            gen.addCertificates(certs);

            byte[] dataSigned= gen.generate(msg, true).getEncoded();
```

Estoy utilizando la Bouncy Castle jdk13 (bcmail, bcpkix, bcprov).

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué error genera? Podrías postear la excepción o error que ocurre.

Comment: Error en algoritmo y si cambio el algoritmo me dice error en el provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lograr la firma detachada implemente esto:

```
byte[] signedVector = null;

CMSSignedDataGenerator signedGenerator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();

List<X509Certificate> certList = new ArrayList<X509Certificate>();
certList.add(cert1);

Store certStore = new JcaCertStore(certList);

signedGenerator.addCertificates(certStore);

ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").build(key);
signedGenerator.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
        new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build()).build(sha1Signer, cert1));

CMSProcessableByteArray cmsByteArray = new CMSProcessableByteArray(Utils.fromBase64(inputBase64File));
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
cmsByteArray.write(baos);

CMSSignedData signedData = signedGenerator.generate(cmsByteArray);

byte[] pkcs7Bytes = signedData.getEncoded();

signedVector = DERtoPEM(pkcs7Bytes, "CMS");
```

El método **DERtoPEM**:

```
    private static final byte[] DERtoPEM(byte[] bytes, String headfoot) {

        byte[] stringBytes = Base64.encode(bytes);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("-----BEGIN " + headfoot + "-----\n");
        String encoded = new String(stringBytes);
        int i = 0;
        while ((i + 1) * 64 < encoded.length()) {
            sb.append(encoded.substring(i * 64, (i + 1) * 64));
            sb.append("\n");
            i++;
        }
        String remainder = encoded.substring(i * 64);
        if (remainder != "") {
            sb.append(remainder);
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        sb.append("-----END " + headfoot + "-----\n");
        return sb.toString().getBytes();
    }
```

Con esto se genera el archivo que tiene el valor del hash firmado. Despues es cuestion de validar el hash del archivo con el hash de la llave y verificar si es el mismo.